# How to compare non-similar words (excel formula)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I work with Excel 2003

I have a **Teams** (example: G50) and each team there are some **Groups** (example: 70-1, 70-2, etc.).

I want to set a condition that determined the following rule (pic example):

[image]

if G50 = 70-1 or 70-2 or 70-3 etc. (up to 5 Groups)

if G51 = 71-1 or 71-2 or 71-3 etc. (up to 5 Groups)

The answer should be: 1-TRUE , 0-FALSE

**examples:**

1. G50=70-5 , 1-TRUE (because the GROUP 70-5 belongs to TEAM G50)
2. G50=71-1 , 0-FALSE (because the GROUP 71-1 does NOT belongs to TEAM G50)
3. G52=70-1 , 0-FALSE (because the TEAM G52 does NOT belongs to GROUP 70-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Array Formula. You have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$11=A1)*(LEFT($B$1:$B$11,FIND("-",B1,1)-1)=LEFT(B1,FIND("-",B1,1)-1)))>1,1,0)`

I created Row 10 and row 11 data to demonstrate that

1. The formula will work even if your data is not sorted
2. Different data format (Should have `-` though)

[image]

**FOLLOWUP**

Array Formulas: See [THIS](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx)

Explaining the formula

`FIND("-",B1,1)`

`FIND` locates one text string within a second text string, and returns the number of the starting position of the first text string from the first character of the second text string. In the above formula I am trying to find "-" in `B1`

I then use `LEFT` to return the characters from the beginning of the string up till `-`.

Then I match it with the rest of the column to find a match. I then use `SUMPRODUCT` to return the sum of all the matches.

To understand how each formula works independently, I would recommend checking Excel's inbuilt help which explains each function with examples.

HTH

Comment: Dear Siddharth Rout, I don't understand your answer & I tried it anyway and It doesn't work :(

Comment: Which part you didn't understand?

Comment: I didn't understand the: ctrl+shift+enter , and your formula - it doesn't work :(

Comment: But which part?

Comment: I didn't understand the: ctrl+shift+enter , and your formula - it doesn't work :(

Comment: If it didn't work, how did I uploaded the snapshot?;) You have to copy the formula from the post above and then instead of pressing enter in the cell, you press ctrl+shift+enter

Comment: I tried it again and it still doesn't work. I used office 2003 if this matter. MY snapshot: http://oi34.tinypic.com/16c3rle.jpg

Comment: That is because you have selected the wrong range :) You have mentioned A1:A11 in the formula whereas your actual range is A2:A13. Similarly B2:B13. and change B1 to B2 after that :)

Comment: OK your right-it works great. I didn't notice, my mistake. CAN YOU PLEASE EXPLAIN A BIT THE FORMULA SO I UNDERSTAND? thanks...

Comment: Sure :). Updating the post. This will take 10 mins.

Comment: OK excellent!!! most Appreciate!!! :)))

Comment: Post updated. You will have to refresh it. The best part of the formula as I mentioned above is that it will work even if your data is not sorted :)

Comment: I'm speechless. Thank you. I mean it. Thanks for the help & explanation. It helped me a lot in my work. :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data given in the picture starts from A2 and the result you expect in C2, use the function `=IF(VALUE(RIGHT(A2,2))+20=VALUE(LEFT(B2,2)),1,0)`
Here is the explanation:

1. RIGHT(A2,2))+20 - checks two characters from right in cell A2 which is 50 and adds 20 to it making it 70
2. LEFT(B2,2) - checks two characters from left in cell B2 which is 70
3. VALUE - The excel returns the numbers 50+20 = 70 of cell A2 and 70 of cell B2 as text.  To convert text to number i use this function
4. IF - If the two characters from right side in cell A2 + 20 is equal to 2 characters from left side of cell B2, then mark as "1", else mark as "0"

Comment: WOW thank you so much! It works great!   

BUT, I forgot to mention something:   

if my data isn't 70-1 but **070-1** , because it doesn't work in this situation :(   

Thanks again <3